# String input/output in C

Tags: c, string

I need to print all even indices of a string together followed by a space and then all the odd indices of string together. I can input as many as string N. Each new string will be on a new line in output with conditions above mentioned.

Below is my code, Can you suggest where i am wrong?

```
int main() {

    int i;
    int N;
    char str[10000];
    scanf("%d",&N);
    while(N>0)
        {
        scanf("%s",str);
        for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
            if((i%2)== 0)
                {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }

            else if((i%2)==1)
                {

                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        N--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((i%2)== 0)
                {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }

            else if((i%2)==1)
                {

                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }` so basically you're doing the same thing in both branches. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You are using only one loop.

Comment: duplicate your loop, check odd in one, and even in the other...

Comment: got it i should add one more for loop.

Comment: for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
            if((i%2)== 0)
                {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
        }
        
         putchar(' ');
         for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
         {
            
            if((i%2)==1)
                {
                
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        N--;
    }

Comment: (1) Don't post code in comments (2) Why iterate over all numbers in steps of 1 and filter them? You can iterate in steps of 2 and **know** your index is even or odd.

Comment: @StoryTeller: One reason to be cautious is that you need to test for end of string — it would not be good to skip over the null byte.  However, if the code established the length of the string, `len = strlen(str);` and then used `for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2)` and `for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2)`, then it would be fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need another loop like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int i, N;
char str[10000];
scanf("%d", &N);

printf("%d\n", N);
while (N > 0) {
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    // Even Indcies:
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        //printf("%d", i);
    }

    printf(" ");

    //Odd Indices
    for (i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        //printf("%d", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
    N--;
}
}
```

In response to @StoryTeller's comment, consider the following C code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int i, N;
char str[10000];
scanf("%d", &N);


while (N > 0) {
    scanf("%s", str);
    //printf("%s\n", str);

    // Even Indcies:
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i+=2) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        //printf("%d", i);
    }

    printf(" ");

    //Odd Indices
    for (i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i+= 2) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        //printf("%d", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
    N--; 
}
```

If I input the following parameters when prompted:

```
2
reallylonginput
short
```

Then I actually get the following output:

```
rallnipt elyognu
sotlnipt hr
```

The first one works just fine, as we would expect. However, the second one contains characters that don't make sense, namely **lnipt** on the first cluster. To see why this happens, we must take a closer look at the str variable.

When the first scanf is called, the input is written to str, and str looks like

```
| r | e | a | l | l | y | l | o | n | g | i | n | p | u | t | \0 | \0 | \0 | ...
```

So the loops were fine for the first input. But when we read in the next input, str looks like

```
| s | h | o | r | t | \0 | l | o | n | g | i | n | p | u | t | \0 | \0 | ...
```

It only overwrites as much as it needs to and leaves everything else left untouched. Since the first loop only scans over the even indices, it misses the first \0 and keeps going. So indexing by two doesn't work.

Comment: Indexing by two does work. One just has to adjust the loop condition accordingly.

Comment: @storyteller can you give me the loop condition for indexing by two if it does works?

Comment: Thanks @eedward that's what i did add one more loop and done but i indexed in increment of 1.